# Custom plugin installation does not stop only works with google chrome dev tools

Tags: c#, plugins, google-chrome-devtools, nopcommerce

i've created a custom plugin called Trail Tracker. I made it step by step after this tutorial

Advanced nopCommerce plugin tutorial from nopCommerce

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hApasYO1hhQ&feature=youtu.be

I am using nopCommerce 3.7 and Visual Studio 2015

After I logged in as admin.
My plugin shows up successful under Local Plugins

http://localhost:15536/Admin/Plugin/List

The plugin is not installed. But I am able to click the install Button.
Then the problem occurs. The installation screen comes, but it doesn't stop.
Even after 20 min it still doesn't stop.

After the server restart the plugin is installed (the Database is created and green ok symbol)

I cannot configre the plugin and it is not working (add a new dropdown menu in admin area)

But I can successfully Remove / Uninstall the plugin.

**EDIT 0**

The strange thing is, when I open the developer tools from Google Chrome and open the tab `Network` the installation only takes seconds.

But I can't configure the plugin and it is not working.

**EDIT 1**

I've changed my code. Now you can configure the plugin, but the dropdown menu is missing.

[image dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA4wP.jpg)

[Code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsYYSVzzwhqzgYEoXmzLYOPXv8pKQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem.
It hast nothing to do with my plugin or the solution of visual studio.

It is the chaching of chrom, in addtion to the caching of iis.

If I reload the page with `Strg + r` befor uninstalling and bevor installing a plugin (doesn't matter which plugin) it works just fine.

**just clear cache** bevor handling with plugins